# reverted with reason string 'ds-math-sub-underflow'

Tags: solidity, pancakeswap

I am trying to add Liquidity to a locally deployed pancakeswap instance.  When calling addLiquidity I get:

*ProviderError: Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'ds-math-sub-underflow'*

I've tried everything on:
[UniswapV2 addLiquidity revert ds-math-sub-underflow](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/97032/uniswapv2-addliquidity-revert-ds-math-sub-underflow), as well as any other post I could find.

My Code:

```
async function main() {
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();

  const PancakeFactory = await hre.ethers.getContract("PancakeFactory");

  const PancakeRouter = await hre.ethers.getContract("PancakeRouter");
  const routerAddress = PancakeRouter.address;

  const Token1 = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");
  const token1 = await Token1.deploy("Token", "TKN", 9999999999);

  const Token2 = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token2");
  const token2 = await Token2.deploy("Token2", "TKN2", 88888888);

  const tx = await PancakeFactory.createPair(token1.address, token2.address);
  var pairAddress = await PancakeFactory.getPair(
    token1.address,
    token2.address
  );

  await token1.transfer(pairAddress, 200);
  await token2.transfer(pairAddress, 200);

  var addr1Balance = await token1.balanceOf(deployer);
  var addr2Balance = await token2.balanceOf(deployer);

  await token1.approve(routerAddress, 100);
  await token2.approve(routerAddress, 100);

  var t1addr = token1.address;
  var t2addr = token2.address;

  console.log(`
  *****************************
  Deployer: ${deployer}
  Factory:  ${PancakeFactory.address} 
  Router:   ${routerAddress}
  Token:    ${token1.address}
  Token2:   ${token2.address}
  T1Bal:    ${addr1Balance.toString()}
  T2Bal:    ${addr2Balance.toString()}
  Pair:     ${pairAddress}
  *****************************
  `);
  var deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 10;

  const addLiquidityResult = await PancakeRouter.addLiquidity(
    t1addr,
    t2addr,
    10,
    10,
    10,
    10,
    deployer,
    deadline
  );
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

TNAR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting for anyone that runs across this issue:

Digging into the Pancake Source, I discovered there is a MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY setting, which is set to 1000.  Setting the addLiquidity values from 10 to > 1000 cured the error.