# I am getting reason: 'invalid BigNumber value', Error. What is the reason?

Tags: uniswapv2

```
wallet = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic)
// console.log(wallet.address)
const signer = wallet.connect(provider);
// console.log(signer)

const routerInstance = new ethers.Contract(routerAddress, routerABI, signer);
const token1 = new ethers.Contract(fromAddress, erc20ABI, provider);
const token2 = new ethers.Contract(toAddress, erc20ABI, provider);





//--------------------------Input variabals--------------------------//




const gasLimit = 20000




//--------------------------Token Swap Function--------------------------//




const TokenSwap = async(amount, fromAddress, toAddress) => {

    const decimal1 = await token1.decimals()
    const decimal2 = await token2.decimals()

    // const amountIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits(amount, decimal1).toString();
    // const amountIn = ethers.BigNumber.from(amount, decimal1).toString();
    const amountIn = ethers.utils.parseEther(amount).toString();
    const amountOut = await routerInstance.getAmountsOut(amountIn, [fromAddress, toAddress])
    console.log(amountIn)

    const output = ethers.utils.formatUnits(amountOut[1].toString(), decimal2)
    console.log(output)
    console.log(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 10)
    const tx = await routerInstance.swapTokensForExactTokens(
        amountIn,
        amountOut,
        [fromAddress, toAddress],
        wallet.address,
        Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 5,
    )
}

amount = "0.000000000000002";
TokenSwap(amount, fromAddress, toAddress);


                ^
```

Here is my error:

```
D:\blockchain\Volume Bot -ruv\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:238
        var error = new Error(message);
    Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=[{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x07d0"},{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x00"}], code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)
        at Logger.makeError (D:\blockchain\Volume Bot -ruv\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:238:21)
        at Logger.throwError (D:\blockchain\Volume Bot -ruv\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:247:20)
        at Logger.throwArgumentError (D:\blockchain\Volume Bot -ruv\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:250:21)
        at BigNumber.from (D:\blockchain\Volume Bot -ruv\node_modules\@ethersproject\bignumber\lib\bignumber.js:239:23)
        at NumberCoder.encode (D:\blockchain\Volume Bot -ruv\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib\coders\number.js:36:39)
        at D:\blockchain\Volume Bot -ruv\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib\coders\array.js:74:19
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at pack (D:\blockchain\Volume Bot -ruv\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib\coders\array.js:60:12)
        at TupleCoder.encode (D:\blockchain\Volume Bot -ruv\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib\coders\tuple.js:71:33)
        at AbiCoder.encode (D:\blockchain\Volume Bot -ruv\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib\abi-coder.js:91:15) {   reason: 'invalid BigNumber value',   code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',   argument: 'value',   value: [
        BigNumber { _hex: '0x07d0', _isBigNumber: true },
        BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true }   ] }
    
    Node.js v20.9.0
```

Comment: Please click the Accept tick ✅ if my answer helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Decoding your error shows that `0x07d0` corresponds to *decimal* `2000`.

And `0x00` corresponds to *decimal* `0`.

Which means that the problem is with one of your `amountIn` or `amountOut` parameters.

Considering `amountIn` is converted to string on this line (`const amountIn = ethers.utils.parseEther(amount).toString();`), you should look into how you're pass `amountOut` in:

```js
const amountOut = await routerInstance.getAmountsOut(amountIn, [fromAddress, toAddress])
```

`amountOut` is actually an array here, you can look that up in the UniswapRouter02.sol **ABI**, or the function here:

```
function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path) public view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
```

So in your **ethers.js** project you should pick a specific slot from the return value and then convert it to string, *because all `BigNumber` values should be converted to string before used in **ethers.js** contracts*.

*Like this:*

```js
const tx = await routerInstance.swapTokensForExactTokens(
        amountIn,
        amountOut[0].toString(),
        [fromAddress, toAddress],
        wallet.address,
        Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 5,
    );
```

Comment: Yay! It solved my problem. I got this error reverting my transaction "Fail with error 'ds-math-sub-underflow'"

Comment: Great that this solved the problem! Regarding the new error, please see this for details about the **ds-math-sub-underflow** exception: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/97032/uniswapv2-addliquidity-revert-ds-math-sub-underflow.

Answer by Turbut Alin: "This also happens if the Uniswap token related to the pool has not been approved for the wallet sending the transaction.

Solution: Call the approve method of the new Pair contract with spender as the Uniswap router address"

**That is likely the culprit in your case**

Comment: You should give the routerInstance the approval to take your tokens.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you. :)

Comment: Thank You it has helped me :)

Comment: Awesome! Then please accept my answer ⬆️